# "Храмы представляют собой типологии зданий" — так можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> **Храмы** так и именуются A, В, C, D и **представляют собой типологии зданий, созданных для поклонений богам**, которые сохранятся на
>   протяжении всей истории римской архитектуры.

Как сделать, чтобы "которые сохранятся" относилось к зданиям?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храмы так и именуются A, В, C, D и представляют собой **типологию зданий,** созданных для поклонения богам, **которая** сохранится на протяжении всей истории римской архитектуры.

**Типология** — это классификация предметов или явлений по общности каких-л. признаков, то есть это перечень типов зданий по какой-то системе.

**Типологии** — различные виды  классификации (в их основе лежат разные принципы). Я думаю, что вряд ли здесь идет речь о различных видах классификации.

Comment: Ну, если A, В, C, D представляют собой все типы, входящие в эту типологию, — тогда да, они представляют эту типологию. А если A, В, C, D - не полный список типов, то можно ли считать, что они представяют эту типологию? В любом случае, причем тут слово "собой"?

Comment: Я так понимаю: названные храмы - это типичные образцы культовых зданий,  а типология - это просто их системное описание, никакой точности в этом термине нет.

Comment: Да, согласен, такое понимание возможно. Меня сбило с толку то, что, по словам Галины, автор - профессионал, а не художник слова.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, *типология* здесь неуместна, можно сказать "типы", "типологические   группы", "типологические разновидности". Надо бы уточнить у архитекторов.

ТИПОЛОГИЯ, -и; ж. [от греч. týpos - отпечаток, образец и lógos - учение] Спец. Научная классификация предметов или явлений по общности каких-л. признаков. Т. языков. Построить какую-л. типологию.

По-моему, сохранятся типы, я не здания. И не сохранятся, а будут воплощаться. И структурная переделка нужна. Например:

Храмы так и именуются: A, В, C, D(,) — и представляют собой **типы** зданий, **предназначенных** для поклонени**Я** богам (точка/запятая/точка с запятой/тире). Эти типы будут воспроизводиться на протяжении всей истории римской архитектуры.

Дополнение.

"Которые сохранятся на протяжении всей истории." — Меня здесь смущает будущее время (столь любимое автором) в сочетании с историей, которая по определению обращена в прошлое. "Нечто происходило на потяжении истории" — понимаю, но "Нечто **будет** происходить на потяжении **истории**" — нестыковка.

Comment: За "поклонениЯ" - спасибо, прозевала; над остальным - думаю.

Answer (score 1):

«Храмы так и именуются A, В, C, D и представляют собой типологию зданий, созданных для поклонений богам, которые сохранятся на протяжении всей истории римской архитектуры».

Храмы так и именуются A, В, C, D и типологически представляют собою здания, созданные для поклонения богам, и останутся навсегда в истории римской сакральной архитектуры.

Comment: Второе - ответ или пояснение к первому?

Comment: Первое — исходное.